# Deserialize Retrofit response when response body is Void

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm using `Retrofit` to get some data from a server. The problem is the response body is null (although I get a response code : 200 ) and if you check this [github issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1446#issuecomment-169564331) like I did you will see that they suggest you to use `Call<Void>` for empty response's body.

I did change it to `Call<Void>` and now when I'm making a request with `Retrofit` it enters `onResponse` and response is successful, but  then I can't deserialize it with `Gson`.

Using :

```
 DataServiceResponse serviceResponse = gson.fromJson(response.body(), DataServiceResponse.class);
```

is not possible since `response.body()` is void.

Comment: why is it then void ?

Comment: if the response body is null, then there is something wrong with your webservice, not with your android code. Have you already test the response from your webservice? I'm suggesting you to use one of firefox plugin called RESTClient

Comment: If I change it to `Call<List<DataServiceResponse>>`  while I get code 200, it enters `onFailure()` method

Comment: OK, maybe you are right - there's something else that's wrong and I shouldn't have added Void as response body.